# BGTaskRequest earlestBeginDate maximum time possible

Tags: ios, bgtaskscheduler

I am interested in understanding what is the farthest future date in time you can schedule a BGTask.  For example is it possible to schedule on 7 days from now?  Also, what if the user has not opened the app for 7 days, does this affect the system decision to fire the task? Apple seems very cryptic about the issue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskrequest/3142244-earliestbegindate

Where can we find the details description of the constraints and capabilities of background tasks.

Update: I watched https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063/ which helped a lot to shed light on many concerns I had.

Comment: I know it’s frustrating, but Apple simply doesn't publish details on these algorithms and they are subject to change, regardless. It's not going to answer your question, but WWDC 2020 video [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063/) offers a few clues.